# Directory To Serialize/Deserialize Objects in Android?

Tags: java, android, file, serialization

I am trying to serialize an object onClick and then in a ListFragment, grab all the files in that directory and put them into the array. I have the code to serialize and put the filenames into an ArrayList, but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it so they both point to the same directory?

Here is my code for serialization:

```
 WIFIQRCODE =   "WIFI:T:"+PASSTYPE2+";S:"+SSID2+";P:"+PASS2;

                    OutputStream file = null;
                    try {
                        file = new FileOutputStream(SSID2+".ser");
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
                    ObjectOutput output = null;
                    try {
                        output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    assert output != null;
                    try {
                        output.writeObject(WIFIQRCODE);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

And my code for getting the filenames in the ListFragment:

```
 String[] filenames = getApplicationContext().fileList();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i = 0; i<filenames.length; i++){
                //Log.d("Filename", filenames[i]);
                list.add(filenames[i]);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filenames);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Any help would be appretitiated!

Comment: Any reason why you are using this method verses Parcelable?  Parcelable generally works better in Android.  Or do you need to persist to file?

Comment: `WIFIQRCODE` is just a `String`, why do you need to store that as `Object`? Also `getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(name)` should put them in the same directory as the one you read.

Comment: I am using this method so I can use them later in future using sessions